# I am getting "Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Recipe[]'.ts(2339)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi I am new at typescript and trying to do a recipe app with React to learn it. My problem is about fetching a single data to a component. I created a generic fetch hook for general using and it does work with getting all recipe to Home page but doesn't work with to fetch a single recipe to Recipe page. Here is my code:

*hooks/useFetch.ts:*

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Recipe } from '../../types/types'

type FetchResult = {
  data: Recipe[] | null
  isPending: boolean
  error: string | null
}

export const useFetch = (url: string): FetchResult => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Recipe[] | null>(null)
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController()
    const signal = abortController.signal

    setIsPending(true)

    fetch(url, { signal })
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error('Could not fetch the data for that resource')
        }
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setIsPending(false)
        setError(null)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Fetch aborted')
        } else {
          setIsPending(false)
          setError(err.message)
        }
      })

    return () => abortController.abort()
  }, [url])

  return { data, isPending, error }
}
```

and my type is in a seperate **types** folder like this:

```js
export type Recipe = {
  id: string
  title: string
  ingredients: string[]
  method: string
  cookingTime: string
}
```

When I try to fetch all recipes in home page there isn't a problem but if I try to fetch a single recipe in Receipe.tsx I can't reach Recipe[]'s props with TypeScript. Here is the code:

*Recipe.tsx:*

[image]

And the erros is:

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Recipe[]'.ts(2339)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hm, I'm not a TypeScript expert but here's my take on it: the `data` state inside your `useFetch` is *expected* to be an Array with items of `Recipe` Objects -> the part that says `Recipe[] | null` maybe modify it into `Recipe | null` what happens then?

Comment: (Additionally, I also expect you to see some similar kind of warning since its data type can be "*`null`*" (`| null`)  you would rather, perhaps, have to modify the initial value of `data` state to be following the `type Recipe` structure, as such: `{
  id: '',
  title: '',
  ingredients: [''],
  method: '',
  cookingTime: ''
}` -> and, remove the `| null` part.)

Comment: @Aleksandar `null` makes perfect sense in case of fetching data, if not found then it's null, while assigning an object initialised with empty values makes much more sense in **Add Form**

Comment: Do you mind to share the response of all recipes and single recipes in the question?

Comment: @Aleksandar I tried both but not working

Comment: @khewdev what do you mean with "response"?

Comment: @xdreva "*not working*" - what error you got when you removed `[]` from `Recipe[]` from the `data` data type?

Comment: @xdreva Could you provide the output of fetching all recipes and single recipes from your API? I am assuming the returned structure is different, please provide if you could

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting "Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Recipe[]'.ts(2339)"

I think you shouldn't mix together a single `Recipe` response with all recipes that are typeof `Recipe[]`, however if you really insist on it, you should add a type guard to check what is the current type of `data`.

```
const recipe = Array.isArray(data) ? data[0] : data;

{recipe?.title && <h1>{recipe.title}</h1>}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=57&pln=13&pc=5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCUSTWDrgF44BvcuOYAEwBccAM4wowAHYBzbnBjAYAGyRDR46bMlSifYEgkxhqsVoDaAXVkgkMABYRBIkxp5oIEANZaAKqBVP1GQBfSjcJUTgAYVxICX14dgAKAEo2AD5OWVcIcPhTPhQYFAAaERsAEUKUczYGdBgAOgBXYSQAZSKYJAAeZCYWAB8GfqQLOCGJJsVFNMTJ6eSKHmzcuCIR2oBBKCgUagbgYW3d6kSCotSAfjhzlFMABhqhW4ostZsmqAk4RLfluG6ugAbmkOOtmEhLg15EokEFugB6YFpN7JcghchAA)